# Legal notice that copying javascript isn't allowed

Tags: javascript, legal

I've build a fun tool for one of our clients. This client is in a competitive business and likes to keep this tool to itself.

As we all know, javascript is quite downloadable, and even obfuscated not that big of a challenge, thus I'm thinking of a comment with a "No, you may not use this for your own site".

Are there any standard texts or procedures to do so? Again, I'm aware this doesn't stop downloading, but it should stop *companies* from taking it, because it would be illegal to use because of the notice.

Comment: It is illegal to copy and use it even without the notice.   Everything you write gets copyright protection.   Your terms of use for your website should give users the right to download, cache it, and use it within your website, but not give permissions beyond that.

Comment: That's what I thought, guess this is a "stating the obvious" kind of notice.

Comment: You can use another language that can reside outside of the web space to write a library of sensitive business rules that can be called. As well, you can use a database for some sensitive code elements, parameters, calculations, etc.

Comment: Agree with @closetnoc here -- offload as much of the load/calculation/logic as you can server side, make JSON available only to this domain in question using `CORS` and/or `JSONP`, and call upon it using JS to display the "results" or whatever via non-descriptive json vars. Example, use `d` for json return, then things like `d.i` (or better yet  pure indecies like `d[1]`) for facets of data within that. This way if someone crawls code at least they have a harder time understanding what the vars mean, and they can't run it because of `CORS` and without reverse engineering your server side.

Comment: Yeah, but that won't work in this case. A lot has to be done clientside, a large part is calculations of html elements, with too many differences per user. The main formulae is serverside, but the client want to do more about the front end (which is neat, and user interactive)

Answer (score 1):

A basic copyright notice which I add to all my script files is...

> This file remains the property of PlanetScale Networks. It may not be copied or used by any third party for any purpose not authorised specifically by PlanetScale Networks.

Having said that it is very much a meaningless stating the obvious kind of statement as whether or not it is in there the file is still my companies property and anyone who uses it without permission is in breach of copyright.

Answer (score 1):

As others have noted here, the legal language would be mostly meaningless, but might make somebody think twice. I am personally not a fan of copyrights, so if possible, I might try to persuade the client to reconsider the challenges of hiding a tool, relative to the benefits of making it open.

However, if you do have a tool that you think is unique and worth obfuscating, I would recommend having as much of it implemented on the server side as possible. You could use AJAX to make PHP calls to parse the data on the server and pass that back. If your company is really that concerned with this product and its benefit, this will even allow you to track its actual use better through logs. Keep in mind that this will put a little more strain on the server, but I think it would better suit the client's agenda.